# PCL Feature matching

Tags: point-cloud-library

Firstly I am new in PCL and I am looking for help in the topic of feature matching for point cloud registration using detectors and descriptors.

my pipeline works as following:

1. load source cloud
2. detect ISS keypoints
3. describe keypoints using FPFH
4. load target cloud
5. detect ISS keypoints
6. describe keypoints using FPFH
7. estimate correspondences
8. correspondences filtering
9. transformation estimation
   finally --> transform source cloud using estimated transformation matrix from step 9

the problems are:

1. The code takes too much time in the normals calculations
2. The results are very bad as shown in Images
   [Results][1]

Code is:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// PCL
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/keypoints/iss_3d.h>
#include <pcl/features/normal_3d.h>
#include <pcl/features/shot.h>
#include <pcl/filters/extract_indices.h>
#include <pcl/registration/correspondence_estimation.h>
#include <pcl/registration/correspondence_rejection_one_to_one.h>
#include <pcl/registration/correspondence_rejection_sample_consensus.h>
#include <pcl/registration/transformation_estimation_svd.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>
#include <pcl/registration/icp.h>
#include <pcl/features/fpfh.h>

using namespace pcl;
using namespace pcl::io;

pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer("Cloud Viewer");
pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer ICPView("ICP Viewer");

double computeCloudResolution(const pcl::PointCloud<PointXYZ>::ConstPtr &cloud)
{
    double res = 0.0;
    int n_points = 0;
    int nres;
    std::vector<int> indices(2);
    std::vector<float> sqr_distances(2);
    pcl::search::KdTree<PointXYZ> tree;
    tree.setInputCloud(cloud);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < cloud->size(); ++i)
    {
        if (!pcl_isfinite((*cloud)[i].x))
        {
            continue;
        }
        //Considering the second neighbor since the first is the point itself.
        nres = tree.nearestKSearch(i, 2, indices, sqr_distances);
        if (nres == 2)
        {
            res += sqrt(sqr_distances[1]);
            ++n_points;
        }
    }
    if (n_points != 0)
    {
        res /= n_points;
    }
    return res;
}

int main(int, char **argv)
{
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr source_cloud(new PointCloud<PointXYZ>());
    loadPCDFile("cloudASCII000.pcd", *source_cloud);
    std::cout << "File 1 points: " << source_cloud->points.size() << std::endl;
    //file 1

    // Compute model_resolution

    double model_resolution = computeCloudResolution(source_cloud);

    pcl::ISSKeypoint3D<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointXYZ> iss_detector;
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr source_keypoints(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>());
    pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree(new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>());

    iss_detector.setSearchMethod(tree);
    iss_detector.setSalientRadius(10 * model_resolution);
    iss_detector.setNonMaxRadius(8 * model_resolution);
    iss_detector.setThreshold21(0.2);
    iss_detector.setThreshold32(0.2);
    iss_detector.setMinNeighbors(10);
    iss_detector.setNumberOfThreads(10);
    iss_detector.setInputCloud(source_cloud);
    iss_detector.compute((*source_keypoints));
    pcl::PointIndicesConstPtr keypoints_indices = iss_detector.getKeypointsIndices();

    std::cout << "No of ISS points in the result are " << (*source_keypoints).points.size() << std::endl;
    std::string Name = "ISSKeypoints1.pcd";
    savePCDFileASCII(Name, (*source_keypoints));

    // Compute the normals
    pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> normalEstimation;
    normalEstimation.setInputCloud(source_cloud);
    normalEstimation.setSearchMethod(tree);

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr source_normals(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);
    normalEstimation.setRadiusSearch(0.2);
    normalEstimation.compute(*source_normals);

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::FPFHSignature33>::Ptr source_features(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::FPFHSignature33>());
    pcl::FPFHEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal, pcl::FPFHSignature33> fpfh;
    fpfh.setInputCloud(source_cloud);
    fpfh.setInputNormals(source_normals);
    fpfh.setIndices(keypoints_indices);
    fpfh.setSearchMethod(tree);
    fpfh.setRadiusSearch(0.2);
    fpfh.compute(*source_features);

    /* SHOT optional Descriptor
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::SHOT352>::Ptr source_features(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::SHOT352>());
        pcl::SHOTEstimation< pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal, pcl::SHOT352 > shot;
        shot.setSearchMethod(tree); //kdtree
        shot.setIndices(keypoints_indices); //keypoints
        shot.setInputCloud(source_cloud); //input
        shot.setInputNormals(source_normals); //normals
        shot.setRadiusSearch(0.2); //support
        shot.compute(*source_features); //descriptors
        */

    //Target Point Cloud

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr target_cloud(new PointCloud<PointXYZ>());
    loadPCDFile("cloudASCII003.pcd", *target_cloud);
    std::cout << "File 2 points: " << target_cloud->points.size() << std::endl;

    // Compute model_resolution

    double model_resolution_1 = computeCloudResolution(target_cloud);

    pcl::ISSKeypoint3D<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointXYZ> iss_detector_1;
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr target_keypoints(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>());

    iss_detector_1.setSearchMethod(tree);
    iss_detector_1.setSalientRadius(10 * model_resolution_1);
    iss_detector_1.setNonMaxRadius(8 * model_resolution_1);
    iss_detector_1.setThreshold21(0.2);
    iss_detector_1.setThreshold32(0.2);
    iss_detector_1.setMinNeighbors(10);
    iss_detector_1.setNumberOfThreads(10);
    iss_detector_1.setInputCloud(target_cloud);
    iss_detector_1.compute((*target_keypoints));
    pcl::PointIndicesConstPtr keypoints_indices_1 = iss_detector_1.getKeypointsIndices();

    std::cout << "No of ISS points in the result are " << (*target_keypoints).points.size() << std::endl;
    savePCDFileASCII("ISSKeypoints2.pcd", (*target_keypoints));

    // Compute the normals
    pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> normalEstimation_1;
    normalEstimation_1.setInputCloud(target_cloud);
    normalEstimation_1.setSearchMethod(tree);

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr target_normals(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);
    normalEstimation_1.setRadiusSearch(0.2);
    normalEstimation_1.compute(*target_normals);

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::FPFHSignature33>::Ptr target_features(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::FPFHSignature33>());
    pcl::FPFHEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal, pcl::FPFHSignature33> fpfh1;
    fpfh1.setInputCloud(target_cloud);
    fpfh1.setInputNormals(target_normals);
    fpfh1.setIndices(keypoints_indices_1);
    fpfh1.setSearchMethod(tree);
    fpfh1.setRadiusSearch(0.2);
    fpfh1.compute(*target_features);

    /* Shot Optional
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::SHOT352>::Ptr target_features(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::SHOT352>());
        pcl::SHOTEstimation< pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal, pcl::SHOT352 > shot_1;
        shot_1.setSearchMethod(tree); //kdtree
        shot_1.setIndices(keypoints_indices_1); //keypoints
        shot_1.setInputCloud(target_cloud); //input
        shot_1.setInputNormals(target_normals); //normals
        shot_1.setRadiusSearch(0.2); //support
        shot_1.compute(*target_features); //descriptors
        */

    // estimate correspondences
    pcl::registration::CorrespondenceEstimation<pcl::FPFHSignature33, pcl::FPFHSignature33> est;
    pcl::CorrespondencesPtr correspondences(new pcl::Correspondences());
    est.setInputSource(source_features);
    est.setInputTarget(target_features);
    est.determineCorrespondences(*correspondences);

    // Duplication rejection Duplicate

    pcl::CorrespondencesPtr correspondences_result_rej_one_to_one(new pcl::Correspondences());
    pcl::registration::CorrespondenceRejectorOneToOne corr_rej_one_to_one;
    corr_rej_one_to_one.setInputCorrespondences(correspondences);
    corr_rej_one_to_one.getCorrespondences(*correspondences_result_rej_one_to_one);

    // Correspondance rejection RANSAC

    Eigen::Matrix4f transform = Eigen::Matrix4f::Identity();
    pcl::registration::CorrespondenceRejectorSampleConsensus<pcl::PointXYZ> rejector_sac;
    pcl::CorrespondencesPtr correspondences_filtered(new pcl::Correspondences());
    rejector_sac.setInputSource(source_keypoints);
    rejector_sac.setInputTarget(target_keypoints);
    rejector_sac.setInlierThreshold(2.5); // distance in m, not the squared distance
    rejector_sac.setMaximumIterations(1000000);
    rejector_sac.setRefineModel(false);
    rejector_sac.setInputCorrespondences(correspondences_result_rej_one_to_one);
    ;
    rejector_sac.getCorrespondences(*correspondences_filtered);
    correspondences.swap(correspondences_filtered);
    std::cout << correspondences->size() << " vs. " << correspondences_filtered->size() << std::endl;
    transform = rejector_sac.getBestTransformation(); // Transformation Estimation method 1

    // Transformation Estimation method 2
    //pcl::registration::TransformationEstimationSVD<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointXYZ> transformation_estimation;
    //transformation_estimation.estimateRigidTransformation(*source_keypoints, *target_keypoints, *correspondences, transform);
    std::cout << "Estimated Transform:" << std::endl
              << transform << std::endl;

    // / refinement transform source using transformation matrix ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr transformed_source(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr final_output(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    pcl::transformPointCloud(*source_cloud, *transformed_source, transform);
    savePCDFileASCII("Transformed.pcd", (*transformed_source));

    // viewer.setBackgroundColor (0, 0, 0);
    viewer.setBackgroundColor(1, 1, 1);
    viewer.resetCamera();
    pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerCustom<pcl::PointXYZ> handler_source_cloud(transformed_source, 150, 80, 80);
    pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerCustom<pcl::PointXYZ> handler_source_keypoints(source_keypoints, 255, 0, 0);

    viewer.addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>(transformed_source, handler_source_cloud, "source_cloud");
    viewer.setPointCloudRenderingProperties(pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 1, "source_cloud");
    viewer.addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>(source_keypoints, handler_source_keypoints, "source_keypoints");

    pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerCustom<pcl::PointXYZ> handler_target_cloud(target_cloud, 80, 150, 80);
    pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerCustom<pcl::PointXYZ> handler_target_keypoints(target_keypoints, 0, 255, 0);

    viewer.addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>(target_cloud, handler_target_cloud, "target_cloud");
    viewer.setPointCloudRenderingProperties(pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 1, "target_cloud");
    viewer.addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>(target_keypoints, handler_target_keypoints, "target_keypoints");
    viewer.setPointCloudRenderingProperties(pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 5, "target_keypoints");
    viewer.addCorrespondences<pcl::PointXYZ>(source_keypoints, target_keypoints, *correspondences, 1, "correspondences");

    pcl::IterativeClosestPoint<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointXYZ> icp;
    icp.setInputSource(transformed_source);
    icp.setInputTarget(target_cloud);
    icp.align(*final_output);
    std::cout << "has converged:" << icp.hasConverged() << " score: " << icp.getFitnessScore() << std::endl;
    std::cout << icp.getFinalTransformation() << std::endl;

    ICPView.addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>(final_output, handler_source_cloud, "Final_cloud");
    ICPView.setPointCloudRenderingProperties(pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 5, "source_keypoints");
    while (!viewer.wasStopped())
    {

        viewer.spinOnce(100);
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::microseconds(100000));
    }
    while (!ICPView.wasStopped())
    {

        ICPView.spinOnce(100);
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::microseconds(100000));
    }
    /*
        // Setup the SHOT features
        typedef pcl::SHOT352 ShotFeature;
        pcl::SHOTEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal, ShotFeature> shotEstimation;
    
        shotEstimation.setInputCloud(model);
        shotEstimation.setInputNormals(normals);
        shotEstimation.setIndices(keypoint_indices);
    
        // Use the same KdTree from the normal estimation
        shotEstimation.setSearchMethod(tree);
        pcl::PointCloud<ShotFeature>::Ptr shotFeatures(new pcl::PointCloud<ShotFeature>);
        //spinImageEstimation.setRadiusSearch (0.2);
        shotEstimation.setKSearch(10);
    
        // Actually compute the spin images
        shotEstimation.compute(*shotFeatures);
        std::cout << "SHOT output points.size (): " << shotFeatures->points.size() << std::endl;
    
        // Display and retrieve the SHOT descriptor for the first point.
        ShotFeature descriptor = shotFeatures->points[0];
        std::cout << descriptor << std::endl;
        */

    return 0;
}
```

Finally thanks in advance and I really appreciate your help ...
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtvUA.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve the spent time, try to remove outliers and downsample, after load the source cloud.

Comment: Firstly Thanks for your reply. I appreciate your help. Secondly do you think that this may increase the efficiency of correspondence estimation ?

Comment: Actually I reached a conclusion that there is a problem regarding correspondence estimation and filtering I have a lot of false matches

Answer (score 0):

i'm doing the same thing and i had similar issue, it turns out it may be because of the keypoints.

At first i compared multiples keypoints classes available in PCL , on different pcd i wanted to reconstruct and noticed the keypoints were not on 'points of interests' in the cloud (like angles) and were not consistent between the two pcd (they did not repeat on the same points).

So i commented the keypoint part, to have the entire (filtered and downsampled) point cloud into the FPFH and it worked alot better.

This allowed me to isolate fine tune the normals and fpfh parameters better so now i can focus on finding the right keypoints estimator and parameters that goes with it.

For reference, my scene is a small room at human scale.
My downsampling has a 0.05f leaf , Cloud normals with Ksearch(10) and a fpfh radius of (0.8).
I also used the second transformation method , relative to your code.
rejector_sac.setInlinerTreshold(0.50); but i'm still not sure about this one.

I hope this piece of information helps future readers as this hasn't been fully solved yet.